# Counting how many times each letter appears in the string

Tags: python

I'm trying to count how many times each letter appears in the string and then display it in a list eg.
The word "hello" would be:
{h:1, e:1, l:2, o:2}
This is my code.

```
    text = input()
    dict = {}
    
    for k in range(len(text)):
      if text[k] in dict:
         count +=1
         dict.update({text[k]:count})
      else:
         count=1
         dict.update({text[k]:count})        


    print(dict)
```

The code works on smaller words but not for words that are >10
Can someone please point out what is wrong or what I am missing.

Comment: Please provide example(s) that don't work.

Comment: You're resetting the count each time, but the count depends on the current value inside your `dict[text[k]]` - it does not depend on the variable you keep using for counting. You can instead do `dict[text[k]] += 1` in your upper check, and `dict[text[k]] = 1` in your lower `else`. However, you can do this by doing `from collections import Counter` and `cnt = Counter(text)`; no need to go through the text step by step. Another thing - do not name your dict `dict` - `dict` is an internally defined function that creates a dictionary.

Comment: Examples that don't work are words like incomprehensibilities, Tergiversation

Comment: It's not about the length, it's about letter order. Try `ababba`, it's fun!

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't see any place where `count` is initialized at all. Was the question edited?

Comment: @MarkRansom, there it is, I can distinctly see `count = 1` =)

Comment: @KlasŠ. Good point! Thinking too linearly I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it's sorta hidden =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to count letter frequencies:

```
d = {}
for letter in text:
    d[letter] = d.get(letter, 0) + 1
print(d)
```

Comment: OP is definitely learning to code, so it's more useful to point out their mistake, instead of using magic class to do everything for them =)

Comment: Can you please explain what the code does new to python.

Comment: @DanielHao: _"When learning a new language…"_ — I'm pretty sure he learns **his first** language.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code around a bit that seems to work:

```
trans = {}
def letterCounter(num):
    for ch in num.lower():
        if ch in trans.keys():
            trans[ch] += 1;
        else:
            trans[ch] = 1;
            
    print('Counts letters shown in the input:')
    for x in sorted(trans):
        print(f"Letter \"{x}\": {trans[x]}")

try:
    usr = input('Please insert your input & press ENTER to count its letters: ')
    letterCounter(usr)
except ValueError:
    print('Input must contain a word or sentence')
```

I know this is a little bit different than what you asked for, but this seems to work very well, and I used [www.cologic.dev](http://www.cologic.dev) to do it. It uses code completion to help you learn and code more efficiently.

Comment: @Marcus np. use LAUNCH50 when signing up, and let me know if you need more help with code